# Tekken versions with Tekken Bowl

Tags: tekken

On my old playstation 2 i loved to play the mini game Tekken Bowl in the original Tekken Tag Tournament. 
Is there any newer (also on other consoles) version of Tekken this mini game is implemented?

Comment: Why the downvote? Please help me to improve my question and leave a comment.

Comment: You're looking for games that meet certain criteria, I'm afraid.  Unfortunately, that's a game recommendation, and not something we can help with.

Comment: Nowadays, we have that in Tekken 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a newer version, but it is as an app.

According to the Tekken Wiki : http://tekken.wikia.com/wiki/Tekken_Bowl

> Tekken Bowl is a side game in the Tekken series. It first appeared in Tekken Tag Tournament, Tekken 5: Dark Resurrection, and later returned again as a free app.
>
> Tekken Bowl was released as a free app in 2011.